# Use post tags for meta keyword content

Tags: wordpress

Seems this should be super simple, but I can't find the right API function to make it work...

I'd like to use a posts tags to populate the keywords meta content...

`<meta name="keywords" content="tags from post go here seperated by commas">`

I've tried this but it creates a link list of each post tag...

`<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo the_tags('',' , '); ?>" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<?php
  $postTags = get_the_tags();
  $tagNames = array();
  foreach($postTags as $tag) {
    $tagNames[] = $tag->name;
  }
?>

<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo implode(",", $tagNames); ?>" />
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks amercader, I just modified it slightly to test if the post has tags, otherwise it will error out...

Comment: you have an error in php, implode function receives array as second parameter.
`<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo implode(",",$tagNames); ?>" />` so this would be meta tag with correct implode function. for more [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: @codebuilders thanks, I've updated the snippet as it is the recommended signature, but it will work both ways. From the docs :    Note:    implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less confusing to use the documented order of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the template function [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) to fetch the data instead of letting WordPress output it for you. You can then loop through this array and output the list however you would like:

```
<?php
if ( $posttags = get_the_tags() ) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag)
        echo $tag->name . ' '; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks hans, I appreciate the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

the_tags() automatically displays a link to each post tag. You could use [get_the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) which returns an array of tag objects, which you can then loop through and get the name of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php if(is_single()) {
        $metatags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
        foreach ($metatags as $tagpost) {
            $mymetatag = apply_filters('the_tags',$tagpost->name);
            $keyword = utf8_decode($mymetatag); // Your filters...
            echo $keyword.",";
        }
    }
    ?>your,key,words" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneline warriant for amercader version.

```
<?php if ( $postTags = get_the_tags() ) : $tagNames = array(); foreach($postTags as $tag) $tagNames[] = $tag->name; ?> <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo implode($tagNames,","); ?>" /> <?php endif; ?>
```